# Select province and average weight of people in those provinces only for provinces which average weight of people < 70

Tags: sql

A table named "people" contains the following fields:

| first_name | weight | gender | province |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 85 | Male | Lubusz |
| B | 95 | Female | Lubusz |
| C | 90 | Female | Silesia |
| D | 95 | Male | Silesia |
| E | 40 | Male | Opole |
| F | 50 | Female | Opole |

How to select the name of province and average weight of people in those provinces, only for provinces which the average weight of people is < 70.

Expected output:

| province | Avg_Weight |
| --- | --- |
| Opole | 45 |

I have tried the following code:

```
SELECT province, AVG(weight) AS "Avg_Weight" 
FROM people 
WHERE "Avg_Weight" < 70
GROUP BY province;
```

However, the result returns the overall average weight of people in every province.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use HAVING clause & not WHERE clause as fiter is to be done on aggregated column.

```
select 
  "province", 
  avg("weight") as avg_weight 
from 
  people 
group by 
  "province" 
having 
  avg("weight") < 70;
```

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/2X4wuYwr)